# Rogue dot in ArcGIS for Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am a regular user of ArcGIS for Desktop (Basic License). Every now and again a drawing will have a green dot appear, see screenshot;

[image]

Sometimes this dot has its coordinates beneath it (as it does here), sometimes it will not. I am unable to select this dot, I cannot find it in any of my layers, and seem unable to remove it.

I have further not been able to identify any pattern of when such a dot appears.

What is this dot, and how can I remove it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. It looks like the dot that appears when you use the "Go to XY" tool and click the "Add Labeled Point" button. That tool also has an option to add a point without the labels, which would explain why sometimes you see it without the coordinates. If that's the case here, it isn't part of any layer, it's a graphic element. I can't say why it's appearing randomly, that dot  should only show up if the user uses that tool. I seem to recall reading about someone else having a problem with it showing up unbidden, but I can't find that now.
2. You should be able to select it and delete it, but use the "Select Elements" tool (the black cursor icon on the "Tools" toolbar) instead of the "Select Features" tool:
   [image]